# how to fire a tag in all url except homepage? |Regex(google tag manager)

Tags: google-tag-manager

hi i want to fire a scroll tag in all pages of my website except homepage with regular expressions in tag manager.
in this question homepage url means "site.com" and not means "site.com/home.html"
thanks for helping.

trying regex in tag manager

Answer (score 2):

You could create a trigger with the condition `Page Path` does not equal `/`.

[image]

Comment: that won't work when the home address has no trailing slash.

Answer (score 1):

Just a regex for page path that's longer than 1 character:

```
.{2,}
```

Should do the trick, Every page path that's shorter than 2 characters will be your homepage. I'm just leaving the allowance for the trailing slash "site.com/"